# Completing trading card set. Getting coupon for game I own

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

When completing Trading Card Sets. Is it possible to get a steam coupon for a game that I already own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the [Steam Trading Card FAQ](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq) there's the following question:

> What do I get when I craft a badge from my Trading Cards?

And regarding coupons it states:

> - a chance to get a discount coupon for a different game or DLC

This different game could be refferring to a different game from the ones you own but because the two previous points to this one are referring to the game from which the cards belong I believe this means you just can't get a coupon for the game you just crafted the badge.

However, the coupon you get is random so there should be a low probability to get one for a game you already own.

Answer (score 1):

I think this coupon system is here to help you to buy games.

Personnally, I'm level 30 on Steam and I never dropped a coupon for a game I already owned.